# Property of solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $a(t),b(t)$ continuous functions in $I$ closed and bounded interval in $\Bbb R$. Let $t_0\in I, y_0\in \Bbb R$ and $y(t)$ solution for 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y'=a(t)y+b(t) \\ 
y(t_0)=y_0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
**Prove** that $\exists c>0, c\in \Bbb R$, which only depends on $||a||_{\infty}$ and $I$, such that $$||y||_{\infty}+||y'||_{\infty}\le c(|y_0|+||b||_{\infty})$$ where $$||f||_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|$$

I thought I might use Gronwall's inequality but I didn't manage to do anything with that so I don't know where to start. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
\|y'\|_\infty\le\|a\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty+\|b\|_\infty.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
y(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^t(a(s)y(s)+b(s))\,ds
$$
and so
$$
|y(t)|\le|y_0|+\|b\|_\infty+\int_{t_0}^t a(s)y(s)\,ds
$$
for $t\ge t_0$ (and similarly for $t\le t_0$). Using Gronwall's lemma we get
$$
|y(t)|\le(|y_0|+\|b\|_\infty)e^{\|a\|_\infty|I|}.
$$
Putting all together gives
$$
\begin{split}
\|y\|_\infty+\|y'\|_\infty
&\le(|y_0|+\|b\|_\infty)e^{\|a\|_\infty|I|}+\|a\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty+\|b\|_\infty
\\
&\le(|y_0|+\|b\|_\infty)e^{\|a\|_\infty|I|}(1+\|a\|_\infty)+\|b\|_\infty\\
&\le(|y_0|+\|b\|_\infty)\left[e^{\|a\|_\infty|I|}(1+\|a\|_\infty)+1\right].
\end{split}
$$

Comment: And what functions have you used exactly to apply Gronwall's lemma?

Comment: Do you know Gronwall's lemma?

Comment: I also don't understand how (after "and so") $\int{b(s)}ds$ became $||b||_{\infty}$